# Proof for $-4\pi^2+48\ne A+B\pi+C\pi^2$ when $(A,B,C)\ne (48,0,-4)$

Tags: pi, transcendental-numbers

I have to prove $-4\pi^2+48\ne A+B\pi+C\pi^2$ when $(A,B,C)\ne (48,0,-4)$
$A,B,C \in \mathbb{Q}$ 
As a part of question I try to solve.

Comment: Presumably you mean for $A, B, C$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, or maybe $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[x]\cong\mathbb{Q}[\pi]$

Comment: Did you mean $(A,B,C)\ne(48,0,-4)$?

Comment: yes, I edit now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What will happen if
$$(C+4)\pi^2+B\pi+(A-48)=0?$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I did alone, but I can't think the continue..

Comment: @zardav, $\pi$ will be a solution of...

Comment: Thanks for help.. I wil approve.. when I can

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is there a simple proof that $\pi$ cannot be algebraic of degree two?

Comment: @Winther, using continued fractions.